# IOS не запускает локальный JS код по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, ios

#### Описание

Писал сайт / программу на стандартном DOM. Так как в некоторых браузерах на телефоне проблемы с прикреплением локальных файлов, слил все файлы в единый html. В android при открытии этого файла автоматически запускаются стили, скрипты и.т.д., но проверки на IOS показали, что там не запускаются JS скрипты.

#### Вопрос

Ни разу не пользовался IOS и очень мало знаю о нем. Возможно проблема элементарная - не знаю. **Как запустить JS код в локальном html файле на IOS, или же как хотя бы попросить у пользователя разрешения запустить его?**

Comment: Скрипты инлайновые как я понимаю? У браузера в iOS (вроде Safari) есть одна особенность, если у элемента нет стиля `cursor: pointer`, от там не сработает события (которые от `MouseEvent` или просто `click`, точно не помню), возможно в этом заключается проблема? Вам стоит показать сам HTML файл, может так будет понятней в чём заключается проблема.

Comment: Возможно также что проблема с совместимостью ( старый добрый Safari :) ).

Comment: @ΝNL993 я тоже думал что ошибка поддержки в браузере или события, но нет. Создал чистый html файл с единственной строкой кода `document.write("It works!");`, и это не заработало. Вот и я делал вывод, что IOS не читает скрипты вообще.

Comment: @ΝNL993 вот [исходники](https://github.com/eccs0103/Cheatsheet). Сам сжатый файл там нету, там особо нет разницы. Весь код собран в теги `style` и `script` в `./pages/search-engine.html`.

Comment: Какая версия то? iOS 12+ прекрасно запускает инлайн скрипты со стилями.

Comment: @nazarpunk версия 16.0.2. Добавил сжатый файл в исходниках в `./pages/compressed.html`, можете сами попробовать. Дело в том что при нажатии на этот файл открывает в приложении 'Файлы', и там не работают скрипты. А при попытке открыть с помощью другого приложения [не показывает](https://imgur.com/AAFkM2H.png) браузеры `Safari` и `Chrome`.

Comment: Из файлов не запустится. Скрипты могут запускаться только, если они получены с сервера. Можете использовать для этого GitHub Pages